# Using ListView inside Recycleriew

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I am using listview inside a RecyclerView. For RecyclerView Item layout, I am using Constraint layout. If set constraint layout height to match_parent, then there is extra space below listview.
If I set constraint layout height to wrap_content, then only one item is displayed in listview. I am so confused. Anybody help me to solve this.
Below is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/world_credits_description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description_1_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/world_credits_description"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description_2_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/description_1_text_view"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cost_1_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.226"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/description_2_text_view" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cost_2_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/cost_1_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/description_2_text_view"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cost_3_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/cost_2_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/description_2_text_view"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cost_1_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/details_list_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.103" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think, that's not good idea when use a list view inside an custom item view. You can use Expandable Listview, it's better.

Comment: @Hoàng Vũ Anh  no I want a list there...

Comment: Why ListView. use RecyclerView in that

Comment: @kashyap how do I use like that. can U give a example

Comment: @Kousalya, create a Recyclerview instance in Parent ViewHolder Construction and add data at onBindViewHolder of the parent Recyclerview adapter

Comment: @Kousalya, check this example.  https://android.jlelse.eu/easily-adding-nested-recycler-view-in-android-a7e9f7f04047

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: @kashyap thank you so much now the problem is solved